# Question about Ring Theory (the sum of two ideals is a ring).

Tags: abstract-algebra

A question I recently encountered was:

"Let $R$ be a commutative ring with one not equal to zero. Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of $R$, such that $I + J = R$. Show that for any positive integers a,b, we have that $I^a + J^b = R$. Hint: What is $I\cap J$?"

Regarding the hint, it becomes apparent that $I \cap J = IJ$.
If we have an element $ij$ of $IJ$ (with $i \in I$ and $j \in J$), then by absorption on the left and right, $ij$ is in both $I$ and $J$. Hence, it is in $I\cap J$.
For the other containment, take$x \in I \cap J$. Since $I + J = R$, there is $i \in I$ and $j \in J$ such that $i + j = 1$. Multiplying $x$ by $(i + j)$, we have $x = ix + xj$ which by absorption is in $R$.

Now, I'm not really sure what to do with the hint. Can anyone give me a further hint for this problem?

Comment: Those ideals are to be taken in a ring, I assume commutative. The only ideals in a field $F$ are $(0)$ and $F$, which would make the proposition rather trivial.

Comment: I'm confused by your phrase, "ideals of a field $R$".  Is $R$ a field?  Fields don't have too many ideals.  Does $R$ have a sublield?  Can you clarify for me?  Also, try $\LaTeX$; it's pretty easy.  To illustrate, I'm a-gonna $\LaTeX$ify your post, yes I am.  Back in a flash!  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your observation A.P. You are correct. I edited the question to indicate that it is a commutative ring with 1 not equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks Robert! I will do that from now on.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can find a brief guide on how to write math on this site.

Comment: Hey, you beat me to it!  Way to go!  Doesn't it look good now!  Like my main squeeze with a new 'do!  Cheers!

Comment: I did catch a few things.  One good way to learn more $\LaTeX$ is to check out the raw text of posts using "edit".  When I see $\LaTeX$ I want to learn, that's what I do.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Robert and A.P.! I'm new to this site, and you guys are making this very easy for me.

Comment: Well, I'm happy to do so!  By the way, nice question, ***endorsed!***

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $I+J=R \Rightarrow i+j=1(i\in I,j\in J)\Rightarrow 1=(i+j)^{a+b}=\Sigma_{k=0}^{a+b} {{a+b}\choose k}i^kj^{a+b-k}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider $R^2$ in the light of what you now know.

(I am assuming your definition of a ring contains a multiplicative identity)

Comment: or another power..

Comment: @Exodd Indeed, but start with the square.